# Regex - do not match any inner brackets if outer brackets are preceded by specific character

Tags: python-3.x, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to come up with a regular expression that solves the following problem:
Of the below string, I only want to match (e):

```
$(a(b)(c)d)(e)
```

Of the below string, I only want to match (e(f)):

```
$(a(b)(c)d)(e(f))
```

The expression I came up with will only exclude the first inner bracket:

```
(?<!\$[^)]*)\(.+?\)
```

Here's the interactive example:
[regexr.com/5n5c1](https://regexr.com/5n5c1)

I use regular expressions in Python 3 with the regex library.

Comment: Is it for JavaScript? What is the rule here? Look, `(?<=\()\w+(?=\)$)` [will do](https://regex101.com/r/FJ0Xr6/1). In PHP, `\$(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))(*SKIP)(*F)|(?<=\()\w+(?=\))` [is probably close](https://regex101.com/r/FJ0Xr6/2) to what you are looking for.

Comment: what language are you coding for?

Comment: What about `$(a(b)(c)e)(d(e))`

Comment: In Python, my second regex suggestion works if you install PyPi regex module, see this [Python demo](https://tio.run/##JY0xC8IwFAb3/oo3FPq9VgriJpZugrgIjk0FtWnNYBpeI0bwv8eA08HdcO7jH7PdxGiebhZPoicdsoUaKnJccWPcWTMGLjIJyUqhciig3XYXcF9VX7Rr5lIxozwfD6eEPSe5axRYvSu0TWpF5sRYD@pCPcn8cmAaZ6FAxv6f9WjsYLwWSFjRwj1xjD8).

Answer (score 1):

Install PyPi regex module (`pip install regex`)  and then you will be able to use

```py
import regex
strs = ['$(a(b)(c)d)(e)', '$(a(b)(c)d)(e(f))']
rx = r'\$(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))(*SKIP)(*F)|(\((?:[^()]++|(?2))*\))'
for s in strs:
  print( [x.group() for x in regex.finditer(rx, s)] )
```

See the [Python demo](https://tio.run/##Xc4xC8IwEAXgvb/ihkLu2lJQt4J0E8RFcGwrqE1rBpNwiRCh/z22Oun04PHBe/bl70ZvYlQPa9gDy1GGxHl2sIVGpHjBK@GNekJJooDfBgci0SUcZsyiTbFFrKvmjNTl@YT1iihriTA7HfbHOXY0/ZP1l4hkMAwOlIZlvEoALCvtEZpQjmyeFgkWEhbyeVkOSvfKS0YOBTjqgGJ8Aw).

*Details*

- `\$(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))(*SKIP)(*F)` - a `$` char and then a substring between the balanced nested round brackets, and then the `(*SKIP)(*F)` verbs make the current match fail and skip it, starting the next pattern search from the place where the skip occurred
- `|` - or
- `(\((?:[^()]++|(?2))*\))` - a substring between the balanced nested round parentheses.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FJ0Xr6/3).